# TCP retransmission inside of docker network

Tags: networking, php, docker, tcp, tcpdump

Just lately our server started experiencing increased CPU usage by the php(Symfony) and mysql processes. For quite some time we been trying to find the cause and we found out that we have big amount of TCP retransmissions in our docker network:

[image]

Firstly we read about some people having issues with php-alpine version docker images, we migrated to debian but the problem is still occuring. Nextly, we tried lowering/changing MTU, still no effect.

Right now we found another interesting thing, when we are capturing the traffic of communication between two docker containers there is no retransmissions and the packet length is equal to 1520. But when we do analyze whole traffic on the machine the length is way higher and the retransmissions occurs.

I'm attaching our config files, please let me know if something more is required.

Our docker-compose file looks as follows:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
    database: {}
    logs: {}


services:
    mysql:
        container_name: foxy_mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes:
            - database:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
          - foxy

    assets:
        container_name: foxy_assets
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/dev/assets/Dockerfile
            args:
                SYMFONY_ENV: ${SYMFONY_ENV}
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/symfony
        depends_on:
            - php

    php:
        container_name: foxy_php-fpm
        image: foxy/php-fpm:latest
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/dev/php/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - ${PHP_PORT}:9000
        extra_hosts:
            - ${APP_DOMAIN}:${NETWORK_GATEWAY}
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/symfony
            - ./logs:/var/www/symfony/var/logs:cached
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - foxy

    nginx:
        container_name: foxy_nginx
        image: foxy/nginx:latest
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/dev/nginx/Dockerfile
            args:
                PHP_PORT: ${PHP_PORT}
                APP_NAME: foxy
        environment:
            APP_NAME: foxy
        ports:
            - ${NGINX_PORT}:80
        depends_on:
            - assets
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/symfony
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx:cached
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - foxy
networks:
    foxy:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: ${NETWORK_SUBNET}
                  gateway: ${NETWORK_GATEWAY}
        driver_opts:
            com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1520
```

PHP Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt update
#RUN apt upgrade
RUN curl --insecure https://getcomposer.org/download/1.10.1/composer.phar -o /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer
RUN deluser www-data && adduser -uid 1000 www-data


ARG APCU_VERSION=5.1.22
ARG APCU_BC_VERSION=1.0.5

# Install build dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
            $PHPIZE_DEPS                \
        ...
            libpcre3-dev                    \
    # Install additional stuff needed for modules
    && apt install -y       \
        libzip-dev              \
    ...
        libssh2-1-dev             \
      libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev   \
        git                     \
    ...
        fonts-liberation          \
    # Instal PHP extensions \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j"$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)"  \
        soap                                                    \
        zip
    # Install PECL extensions
RUN pecl install apcu-$APCU_VERSION                   \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu --ini-name 20-apcu.ini \
    && pecl install apcu_bc-$APCU_BC_VERSION             \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apc --ini-name 21-apc.ini \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap
COPY docker/dev/php/symfony.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
COPY docker/dev/php/symfony.ini /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/
COPY docker/dev/php/symfony.pool.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

COPY docker/dev/php/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s /etc/init.d/php-fpm7 /usr/bin/php-fpm7 \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh


 Clean up
RUN apk del .build-dependencies \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

deluser www-data
#addgroup -g 1000 www-data
adduser -uid 1000 www-data
# -G www-data -g 'Linux User named' -s /bin/sh -D www-data
dir='/var/www/symfony/web' && ls -a $dir | grep -v 'uploads' | sed 1d | sed 1d | while read r; do chown -R www-data:www-data $dir/$r; done

su www-data <<USER
    APP_ENV=dev composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --apcu-autoloader --no-interaction --no-progress
    php bin/console fos:js-routing:dump
    php bin/console bazinga:js-translation:dump
    php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
    php bin/console sylius:rbac:initialize

    rm -rf var/cache/*
    rm -rf var/logs/*
    rm -rf var/sessions/*

    chown -R www-data:www-data var/*
    php bin/console cache:warmup --env=dev
USER

php-fpm -F
```

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:stable

#FOR SSL GENERATE
RUN apt install openssl;

ARG PHP_PORT

COPY docker/dev/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY docker/dev/nginx/custom-errors.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY docker/dev/nginx/symfony.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY docker/dev/nginx/error_pages/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server php:${PHP_PORT}; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

# ensure www-data user exists
RUN set -x ; \
#  addgroup -g 1000 -S www-data ; \
    deluser www-data && \
  adduser -uid 1000 www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

COPY web /var/www/symfony/web
COPY .env /var/www/symfony

COPY docker/dev/nginx/error_pages/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY docker/dev/nginx/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

entrypoint.sh for nginx:

```
#!/bin/sh


. /var/www/symfony/.env

mkdir /etc/nginx/certs
chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/nginx/certs

openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj "/C=CA/ST=QC/O=Company, Inc./CN=$APP_DOMAIN" -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:$APP_DOMAIN" -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt

sed -i -e "s~#APP_DOMAIN~$APP_DOMAIN~g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/symfony.conf

nginx
```

Thank you :)